# Can I not use the article 'the' before the word 'selective note-taking'?

Tags: definite-articles

I used the grammar check website, and I got this result.

Selective note-taking is more efficient.
*Selective note-taking technique is more efficient. (error)
The selective note-taking is more efficient.
The selective note-taking technique is more efficient.

Why is it ungrammatical to say 'selective note-taking technique' without the article 'the', while it is grammatical to say 'selective note-taking' without the article 'the'?

Thanks for your attention, have a great day!

Comment: It's okay to include an article in a construction like ***The SHOUTING technique** [is very effective]* because even if you've never heard of that particular "technique" before, the mere fact that I referred to it using a definite article tells you that there ***is*** such a "thing". But it's *not* okay to say ***The shouting is very effective*** unless the context has already clearly established *which* "specific act of shouting" we're talking about (for example, you just watched a couple arguing, and you're making the point that you think the one who shouted loudest won the argument! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your help. Your explanation is so kind and easy to understand. Still, I have one issue unsolved. You explained why it is ok to use the definite article 'THE' before "SHOUTING". Then, my question is, why it is ok not to use 'THE' before "selective note-taking"? I mean, why the sentence "Selective note-taking is more efficient" is grammatical?

Comment: I'd say it's because *most* "gerund" nouns (such as your ***note-taking*** and my ***shouting***) are simply too "generic" to justify including a definite article unless the context clearly identifies and refers to ***a specific instance*** of the activity. Exceptions include gerunds identifying particular sports activities known to millions, where *I like to watch [**the**] **racing** on TV* is fine with or without an article.  But even there, *They cancelled [**the**] racing today because of a bomb threat* is a bit "off" with no article because it refers to a *specific* event on a day.

Answer (score 0):

The definite article is used before nouns that are specific or particular.

The word **The** tells the reader that the noun is, well, definite.

For example:  *The dog ate my ice cream.*

This sentence tells the user that a particular dog ate the ice cream.